# Is there a way to make the output/terminal in VS Code cleaner?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

So like when it outputs it just outputs what it needs to and not like the file name and all that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK5dx.png)

Comment: Wouldnt know. The internet is one big place but I have not seen anything from me trying to find out the answer before I posted this.

Comment: Well if you have the answer I'd love to here it....

Comment: If you search SO you get al least 1 hit every week. The answer is in my first comment

Comment: huh? wdym so???

Comment: What is the name of this site?

Comment: ohhh I see lol. Also wdym is what do you mean. Do you have answer to my question

Comment: See the 4th comment

Comment: That doesnt answer my question........

Comment: Why not? It is the answer to both questions.

Comment: anyone who uses VS Code know how to make the output screen look much cleaner so it only shows the output and not the file name etc

Comment: Ha I just double checked google for an answer and my question is literally the first to some up! XD

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no direct way to omit the path information displayed in the VS Code internal terminal "Terminal". This information shows us the python path used and the path of the executed file when executing the command.

However, you could refer to the following workarounds:

1. Please use the debugging function.

   Use settings in "launch.json":   `"console": "internalConsole",`

   Then click `F5`, the result is displayed in "DEBUG CONSOLE" and it only displays the output result:

   [image]
2. Please try to use related VS Code extensions, such as "Code Runner".

Reference: [Integrated Terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) and [Debug console in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_console).